# error desconocido de consulta api HTTP CORS

Tags: cors

Tengo este error

```
   error
: 
ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'abort', …}
headers
: 
fe {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message
: 
"Http failure response for https://www.dominio.com/api/login: 0 Unknown Error"
name
: 
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
: 
false
status
: 
0
statusText
: 
"Unknown Error"
url
: 
"https://www.dominio.com/api/login"
```

Estuve leyendo y pienso que es CORS, el problema es que no sé cómo solucionarlo, ya que tengo como servidor FORGE y no sé cómo modificar los htacces etc.

Es una aplicacion IONIC, la app cuando ejecuto `ionic serve` para probar, todo me sirve al 100, en postman las solicitudes funcionan, el probelma es que cuando la app la transformo a APK,La instalo en android y me da error, ya tengo el permiso de internet ya que pensaba que era eso y no, ya no se que hacer.

Comment: hola como sabes que es CORS?, probastes via postman y te funciona?

Comment: Sii, se me olvido recalcar, en postman todas las solicitudes me funcionan correctamente, la aplicacion es ionic, y usando ionic serve me funciona todo al 100, el problema es cuando la exporto a APK, ahi es cuando ya no me sirve y me da ese error

Comment: esto es por el empaquetado de ionic

Comment: y como puedo resolverlo?

Comment: debes hacer el build, y correr el emulador de android alli te daras cuenta de una config que te falta

Comment: ya lo hice y no me da ningun error

Comment: tecnicamente no veraz un error, tienes que hacer el deploy al android en las opciones que te da ionic, alli podras colocar el inspector de errores